# How to create column jsonb on AWS-Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, amazon-redshift-spectrum

I have a table in my demo database.

```
CREATE TABLE airports_data (
    airport_code character(3) NOT NULL,
    airport_name text NOT NULL,
    city text NOT NULL,
    coordinates super NOT NULL,
    timezone text NOT NULL
);
```

In the Postgres Database, the data in the coordinate column has POINT as data type, and are like this :

> {"x":129.77099609375,"y":62.093299865722656}

When copy the table to csv file, the data are represent like this in the csv file :

> "(129.77099609375,62.093299865722656)"

As i defined SUPER as data type for the column coordinate in redshift,how can i copy data type POINT from database postgres to csv file, and load csv file to redshift ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Amazon Redshift the [SUPER](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_SUPER_type.html) data type is used to store semi-structured data.

[This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/super-overview.html) is the Amazon Redshift guide for loading and manipulating semi-structured data using the the SUPER data type.

As an example, if you have:

```
CREATE TABLE "public"."tmp_super2"
  ("id" VARCHAR(255) NULL, "data1" SUPER NULL, "data2" SUPER NULL)
  BACKUP Yes;
```

With a CSV file named somefile.csv like this:

```
a|{}|{}
b|{\"a\":\"Hello World\", \"b\":100}|{\"z\":\"Hello Again\"}
```

Then you can load it with a COPY command like this:

```
COPY "public"."tmp_super2"
FROM 's3://yourbucket/yourfolder/somefile.csv'
REGION 'us-west-1'
IAM_ROLE 'arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/RedshiftRole'
DELIMITER '|' ESCAPE
```

The COPY command is picky about double quotes when it is loading SUPER from CSV, hence the use of a pipe field delimiter, and escaping the double quotes.

Comment: Hi @shepo thank you. It's correct. The  two columns (airport_name, city) in the csv file have data json format. How to copy data json format for specific column when copy csv file to redshift ?

Comment: Updated to add an example

Comment: I have as error that the Delimiter is invalid, in the table stl_load_errors. I have a line of data in my csv file : `YKS,Yakutsk Airport,"(129.77099609375,62.093299865722656)",Asia/Yakutsk `

Comment: In the example you have there, the value inside the double quotes is not valid JSON. I think you just need a VARCHAR or maybe a GEOMETRY for that: not a SUPER